# How to prevent some users to open a document from a Lotus view?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

I have:

- a Lotus view which holds lots of documents,
- a field X on every document, which holds users, who should be able to open this document.

How can I prvent opening a particular document for all users except those listed in filed X?
I guess this could be done through QueryOpenDocument event, but would need some assistance on how to construct the code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QueryOpenDocument`, view selection formula and other things like that are not a good way to prevent users from opening your document as a security measure.

A user may create a personal view or copy your database and/or documents to another place (flash usb, etc).

Security measures should involve:

1. [Encryption](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-field_encryption/) (via public and/or secret encryption keys)
2. [Readers](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/reader-names/) access, via `Readers` field (a special field, which content is usernames of authorized users, who can read this document).

In some cases you may need to prevent opening a document from view, not for security reasons, but just to solve a particular task.

For instance, if your view shows documents which should not be opened with any form.

In this case, open view in designer, go to `QueryOpenDocument` and add some code like that:

```
Sub Queryopendocument(Source As Notesuiview, Continue As Variant)
    Dim doc2BeOpened As NotesDocument

    Set doc2BeOpened =  Source.Documents.getFirstDocument()

    'checking MyField value to decide, open or not open the document
    If doc2BeOpened.MyField(0) = "some value" Then
        continue = False 'preventing `open document` action
    End If
End Sub
```

To allow opening a document make sure that `Continue` variable is equal to `True`. It is `True` by default.

---

---

---

**UPDATE №1**

If your document contains a list of common user names, then you can use the following code:

```
Sub Queryopendocument(Source As Notesuiview, Continue As Variant)

    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim userName As String
    Dim whoAllowed2ViewDoc As Variant

    Dim doc2BeOpened As NotesDocument

    userName = session.CommonUserName

    Set doc2BeOpened =  Source.Documents.getFirstDocument()

    'let say your field name is AllowedPeopleNames
    'you can use doc2BeOpened.AllowedPeopleNames or doc2BeOpened.GetItemValue("AllowedPeopleNames")
    'both (without (0) at the end, will return you a variant array with names)
    whoAllowed2ViewDoc = doc2BeOpened.GetItemValue("AllowedPeopleNames")

    If Not Isnumeric(Arraygetindex(whoAllowed2ViewDoc, userName)) Then
        continue = False 'preventing `open document` action if userName is not listed in whoAllowed2ViewDoc array   
    End If  
End Sub
```

Please note, that the code above works for common user names.

- `John Smith` - is a common username
- `John Smith\IT\Acme` - is abbreviated username
- `CN=John Smith\OU=IT\O=Acme` - is fully qualified name (canonical form).

To get fully qualified name (also named as `canonical` form), you can use `session.username`
To get abbreviated form of name, get fully qualified username, then use `NotesName` class, built with fully qualified name as a parameter and then get an abbreviated form of name from it.

```
Dim notesName as NotesName
Dim abbreviatedUserName as String

Set notesName = New NotesName( fullyQualifiedName )
abbreviatedUserName = notesName.Abbreviated
```

---

---

---

**UPDATE №2**

Be careful when checking username presence in the array. The first thing you need to determine what form is using for names, stored in that (field) array `AllowedPeopleNames`.

If names in this array looks like:

```
"John Smith"
"Luis Brown"
"Antony Stoppard"
```

then this array contains common usernames, and you need to get username for checking like that:

```
Dim session as New NotesSession
Dim username as String

username = session.CommonUserName
```

---

If names in this array looks like:

```
"John Smith/IT/Acme"
"Luis Brown/IT/Acme"
"Antony Stoppard/IT/Acme"
```

then this array contains names in abbreviated form. And you need to get username for further checking using this approach:

```
Dim session as New NotesSession
Dim notesName as New NotesName(session.username)
Dim username as String

username = notesName.abbreviated
```

---

And If names in this array looks like:

```
"CN=John Smith/OU=IT/O=Acme"
"CN=Luis Brown/OU=IT/O=Acme"
"CN=Antony Stoppard/OU=IT/O=Acme"
```

then it contains names in canonical form. And you should get username for checking with this array using the following approach:

```
Dim session as New NotesSession
Dim username as String

username = session.username
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Rafael.
I know about Readers and Authors approach and use it extensively. But in this case I have a specific request from the customer to enable anyone to see document in  view and prevent some users from opening them.

Comment: Hm, i hit to another problem.
MyField is a list of Lotus usernames. Therefore I should have some For or While loop which would check not only (0), but all list members if they are equal to current user's username.
Can you help here also?

Sorry for a begginers question, but I am a begginer in LotusScript.

Comment: @Rob, moment, I will update my answer shortly with more relevant code.

Comment: Hi,
First of all, thanks a lot for dealing with my problem.
I put all your code to my application and tried. It didn't worked. I was always blocked regardles to be in AllowedPeopleNames or not.
I did LS Debugging and observed changes in variables.
This is what I saw. 1. userName was my correct Cannonicalized name. 2. whoAllowed2ViewDoc was filled with names from AllowedPeopleNames field and my correct name was among them (the last one in a list). 3. IF loop did not recognized that I should be able to get continue = True

Comment: @Reb please clarify, what form of names (common, abbreviated, canonical) are used for names stored in `AllowedPeopleNames` ?

Comment: @Reb I have updated my answer again. Please check it.

Comment: I second Rafael's statement emphasising that this won't provide effective  security. I'd also recommend against using lists of names, and try to use lists of groups or roles instead. This will be easier to maintain as people shift jobs in the future. Roles would be ideal, because I believe you could use a Form formula with @UserRoles to check if the user has the appropriate role, and if not switch the form to one that is just a mostly blank page with text that says "You do not have the correct role to see this information".